# How can I change crashlytics ID which is set on Eclipse

Tags: crashlytics

I started to work with a computer which on its eclipse crashlytics is setup by someone else's email.
How can I change it. I uninstalled and installed crashlytics plugin but it is still on the other account.
I need to change the ID and continue working with my own ID.

Answer (score 1):

Hemal from Crashlytics here, love to help out with this! When the plugin is in focus, just hit Ctrl+L to logout :)